# Getting Sum of db field using join active record in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-2

I have a table name products with all product details and another whs_products with quantity details of the products for each warehouse.

i want select id, code and name from products table and sum of quantity where products.id = whs_products.product_id

I am trying this

```
$this->db->select("id, code, name");
$this->db->from("products");
$this->db->join('whs_products', 'products.id = whs_products.product_id');
$this->db->select("quantity");
```

I getting the list products that exists in whs_products not the sum. Some products are listed twice as they have 2 entries in whs_products.

**I want list all the products once only where no quantity I want put 0 in quantity and where its is more than 1 in whs_products I want display sum of all the quantity**

Help will be much appreciated!

Table Structure

```
Products
id, code, name, unit, price

whs_products
id, product_id, warehouse_id, quantity
```

I have **whs** table too for warehouse
**id, name, address**

---

I tried this Sir,

```
$this->db->select("products.id as productid, products.code, products.name, products.unit, products.cost, products.price,   sum(whs_products.quantity) as 'totalQuantity'")
->from('products')
->join('whs_products', 'whs_products.product_id=products.id', 'left')
->group_by("products.id");
$this->db->get();
```

Every thing is fine. But the total number of products are calculated wrongly. I think system add 1 to total products, each time gets quantity from whs_products. For some products quantity is 2 or 3 time depending on each warehouse.

Any solutions for this. **I am very thankful for your support.**

Comment: There doesn't seem to have any `sum` in your query...

Comment: Yes, I don't have any idea who to do this :( Sorry

Comment: Can you provide us the structure of your tables, what you have with your current request, and what you expect please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try out the following query and comment.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58866/4)

Sample data:-

Products

```
PID     PNAME
1   j
2   k
3   m
```

whs_Products

```
WID     PID     QUANTITY
11  2   300
11  2   200
14  2   500
11  1   300
15  3   100
14  3   800
```

Query to get total by pid in `whs_products`

```
select pid, wid, sum(quantity) 
from whs_products
group by pid, wid
;
```

Results:

```
PID     WID     SUM(QUANTITY)
1       11      300
2       11      500
2       14      500
3       14      800
3       15      100
```

query using a variable to get user input for `pid` and by pid, wid

```
-- group by pid and wid
set @var:='2'
;
select a.pid, b.pname, a.wid, sum(a.quantity) 
from whs_products a
join products b
on b.pid = a.pid
where a.pid = @var
group by a.pid, wid
;
```

Results:

```
PID     PNAME   WID     SUM(A.QUANTITY)
2       k   11  500
2       k   14  500
```

final query to show quantity by user input pid only

Query:

```
-- by pid only    
set @var:='2'
;
select a.pid, b.pname, sum(a.quantity) 
from whs_products a
join products b
on b.pid = a.pid
where a.pid = @var
group by a.pid
;
```

Results:

```
PID     PNAME   SUM(A.QUANTITY)
2       k   1000
```

### Since OP wants in CodeIgniter

Here is a headstart for you to try. At first I had the impression you already know the syntax of `codeigniter` and you are looking for SQL logic, so you could convert it into the desired format you need.

```
$this->db->select("a.pid, b.pname, count(a.quantity) as 'toalQuantity'");
$this->db->from('wsh_products a');
$this->db->join('products b', 'a.pid=b.pid', 'inner');
$this->db->group_by("a.pid"); 
$where = "a.pid = 2";
$this->db->get();
$query->results_array();
```

Or write a funciton :) :

```
function getQuantity($prodid = false)
{
  $this->db->select(a.pid, b.pname, count(a.quantity) as 'toalQuantity');
  $this->db->join('wsh_products a', 'a.pid=b.pid');
  if ($prodid !== false)
    $this->db->where('a.pid', $prodid);
  $query = $this->db->get('products b');

  if($query->result() == TRUE)
  {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
      $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

---

### Edit as OP requested for `LEFT JOIN` in comments

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b178/11)

To show all products in Products table, do the following:

- In `select` show `pid` from `Products` table.
- Use `from Products Left Join Whs_Products`
- `Group by pid` from `Products` table

Comment: @Saleem I am not personally using `codeigniter`. But I could find out some helpful tips along this answer :)

Comment: You are great! It worked. but changed a and b with table names. Last Question Now its showing the products that exist in whs_products. I want list all the products in products table and where its isn't in whs_products i want show 0 in quantity. help!

Comment: Here SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b178/5 Its showing only 3 products I want all products last 2 with 0 quantity. Thank you for help

Comment: @Saleem getting all products in `Products` table although they might not be in `whs_Products` table is mainly depending on **LEFT JOIN**. In your question it was not mentioned. So I gave you the `inner join`. But I was thinking you may need the `LEFT JOIN`. `SQLFiddle` is a sample. And please know SQLFiddle is a sample. So in your real tables you may add all the data and try out :)

Comment: @Saleem Please take a look at the update. And **for the benefit of all of us in the community**, could you pleaes update your question (append it) with the correct working code ignitor query code? :) Thanks

Comment: I have added my solution at the end of question. I have a problem system is add extra number to total products as get quantity from whs_products. I have 49 products and 2 products have distributed in 2 warehouse (have 2 entries in db). Now I am getting total products 51 :(

Comment: @Saleem get the `total` from `products table`, that's where you have your exact right products, isn't there?

Comment: Yes that's right. But I am using this queries to generate datatables. So the total products are calculated auto :(

Comment: Sorry :( 1 more question can i replace null with 0.

Comment: Even if you look at the `left join` query it gives you the correct total number of products. You can replace null with 0, please use `case when` or `repalce`. +1 for you.

Comment: Can i use case or replace in SQL query :D any help with example is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `(CASE WHEN count(a.quantity) Is Null THEN 0 ELSE count(a.quantity) END) as 'toalQuantity'`

Comment: Saleem even much efficient if you use `COALESCE` to handle null, so you could totally no need to use `CASE`

Comment: Sir, I can't use COALESCE(NULL, 0) because of (,) comma as i am exploding the select query later :( But CASE is working fine.

Comment: Saleem in this community, you don't have to call anyone "sir". Relax and feel free. No one is obliged. :-) [tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html) and some posts from [Ellislab](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/204658/). Good luck.